# Checking tcp checksum

Tags: tcp, checksum

I have the following packet (in hexadecimal):

```
45 00 00 2C
14 3C 40 00
80 06 63 39
C0 A8 01 02
C0 A8 01 04
11 EF 00 7C
4F BF BB FE
18 DF 7A 77
50 18 00 40
02 41 00 00
78 70 00 01
```

In which I have identified the IP header:

```
45 00 00 2C
14 3C 40 00
80 06 63 39
C0 A8 01 02
C0 A8 01 04
```

the TCP header:

```
11 EF 00 7C
4F BF BB FE
18 DF 7A 77
50 18 00 40
02 41 00 00
```

And the data

```
78 70 00 01
```

I'm trying to verify the checksum. For this, I sum up all the fields in the TCP header except the checksum field, which gives me `201D6`

Then I sum up the data bytes, which adds to `7871`

Then I add the computed TCP length (which is 24) the protocol, and the IP source and destination addresses; total: `18380`

Adding the three last marked quantities its `3FDC7` And suming the most valued digit with the rest of the number is `FDCA` which turns into `0235` when computing its one complement. Nevertheless that is different from the checksum from the original packet.

Where did I mess up things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is two error in the computation:

The first one is a simple one, you sum up 24 for the TCP length, but the length has to be in hexadecimal, so it's `0x0018`.

The second one is more tricky, the [RFC 793](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc793) says:

> The checksum field is the 16 bit one's complement of the **one's**
> **complement sum** of all 16 bit words in the header and text.

So it's not just a simple sum of a 16 bit words but a **one's complement sum**, this [forum answer](https://web.archive.org/web/20180209015039/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/54379.html) explains how it works:

> 1. Add the 16-bit values up. Each time a carry-out (17th bit) is  produced, swing that bit around and add it back into the LSb (one's
>    digit). This is somewhat erroneously referred to as "one's complement
>    addition."
> 2. Once all the values are added in this manner, invert all the bits in the result. A binary value that has all the bits of another binary
>    value inverted is called its "one's complement," or simply its
>    "complement."

Doing this you will find:

- `0x01D8` for the TCP header without the checksum
- `0x7871` for the data
- `0x8375` for the pseudo-header

  - `0x0018` for the TCP length
  - `0xC0A0102` for the IP src
  - `C0A80104` for the IP dst
  - `0x0006` for the protocol

The 16 bit one's complement sum and the complement of all this gives **`0x0241`** which is the right result.

Comment: TCP length=: The length of the TCP segment, including both header(20B)and data(4B)=24B=`0x0018`.